# Cannot create a PowerPivot data connection (PerformancePoint Services in SharePoint Server 2013)

Tags: excel-services, performancepoint, powerpivot

I can create data sources that connect to SQL Analysis Servier 2012 instances, but not to the PowerPivot instance.

I followed the instructions here:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff191197.aspx

I used a connection string like this:

```
PROVIDER=MSOLAP;DATA SOURCE=http://contoso/Documents/PowerPivot_Sample.xlsx
```

I get the following error after trying to select a cube from the drop down:
[image: An error occurred connecting to this data source]

The Event viewer gives the following error:

```
The Unattended Service Account "mydomain\myuser" does not have access to the server specified by the data source connection string.

Data source location: http://spdev2013-3/sites/testbicenter/Data Connections/19_.000
Data source name: New Data Source 10

Exception details:
Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.AdomdConnectionException: A connection cannot be made. Ensure that the server is running. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AnalysisServices.SharePoint.Integration, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.XmlaClient.WCFConnect(String dataSource, String dataSourceVersion, String& timeLastModified, String& databaseId, String& databaseName, String& loginName, String& serverEndpointAddress)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.XmlaClient.OpenWcfConnection(ConnectionInfo connectionInfo)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.XmlaClient.Connect(ConnectionInfo connectionInfo, Boolean beginSession)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.XmlaClient.Connect(ConnectionInfo connectionInfo, Boolean beginSession)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.AdomdConnection.XmlaClientProvider.Connect(Boolean toIXMLA)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.AdomdConnection.ConnectToXMLA(Boolean createSession, Boolean isHTTP)
   at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.AdomdClient.AdomdConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.PerformancePoint.Scorecards.DataSourceProviders.AdomdConnectionPool`1.c__DisplayClass4.b__2()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.c__DisplayClass5.b__3()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SecurityContext.RunAsProcess(CodeToRunElevated secureCode)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(WaitCallback secureCode, Object param)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(CodeToRunElevated secureCode)
   at Microsoft.PerformancePoint.Scorecards.DataSourceProviders.AdomdConnectionPool`1.GetConnection(String connectionString, ConnectionContext connectionCtx, String effectiveUserName, CultureInfo culture, NewConnectionHandler newConnectionHandler, TestConnectionHandler testConnectionHandler, String targetAppId)
```

Following the instructions [here](http://stevemannspath.blogspot.ca/2013/04/sharepoint-2013-dashboard-designer-not.html) I installed:

1. Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012 ADOMD.NET and Microsoft® Analysis Services OLE DB Provider for Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012 from the Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012 Feature Pack on the WFE and the server running the PPS Service
2. Microsoft® SQL Server® 2008 R2 ADOMD.NET and Microsoft® Analysis Services OLE DB Provider for Microsoft® SQL Server® 2008 R2 from the Microsoft® SQL Server® 2008 R2 Feature Pack on the WFE and the server running the PPS Service

More info on why these steps are required is [available here](http://www.chrismcnulty.net/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=74).
Also because of a suggestion on [this page](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/performancepoint/archive/2011/12/21/will-sql-server-quot-denali-quot-models-work-as-performancepoint-data-sources.aspx) I installed SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1 to update the components

I also tried to redeploy the [PowerPivot farm solution](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff487868.aspx).

I also verified the PowerPivot installation according to [these instructions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210616.aspx#verifyinstall) and I can view Excel spreadsheets that use PowerPivot in Excel Services, so I think that means it is working correctly.

Answer (score 1):

On the server hosting the SSAS instance install the desktop experience.  When accessing workbooks as a data source from SharePoint, it will connect via WebDav.  WebDav is not available on the server by default and is included when you install the desktop experience feature.

```
Add-WindowsFeature Desktop-Experience
```

Comment: Thanks I tried this but I'm still getting the same exception.